# Distance between points at circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

May be someone can help me to solve the problem. There are circle with radius R1 and circle with radius R2. We also know the distance between A and O and that angle AOB = $\phi$. The aim is to calculate distance between B and C.
I've tried to use sine and cosine theorems but didn't get any results.

You can see picture here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As You have mentioned, by cosine theorem, $AB$ is known.

From that, with the given, $\angle A$ can then be found by sine theorem.

In $\triangle AOC$, since $AO, OC$ and $\angle A$ are known, apply cosine theorem again to find $AC$. Result then follows.